# Retrieve specific cell value from multiple excel files in ms access form textbox using vba

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have total 171 excel Files named like IFSCB2009_01.xls to IFSCB2009_171.xls which are stored in "C:/IFSC" Directory. All files have a column named "IFSC" in B1 (which is code of a bank) in Sheet1 and Column "BankName" in E1 (which is name of bank, related to that IFSC Code).

I have a Form in MS Access with a 2 TextBox, named txtIFSC and txtBankName and 1 button, named cmdSearchBankName. If I enter a IFSC code in txtIFSC and click on cmdSearchBankName then I want to retrieve bank name in txtBankName by searching all 171 excel files without opening. I want value in txtBankName from sheet1, column BankName where IFSC matches with txtIFSC value.

I have no idea of vba code for above procedure.

Comment: Search for "query excel via adodb connection" and that should get you the info you need.  If you are still stuck, come back and post your attempted code and we can help you sort it out.

Comment: There is more then 5-6 lakhs rows in total 171 excel files so database may be slow and extra data in database. So retrieve data directly from excel without importing is more beneficial. So suggest me code that way.

Comment: If you want to read the data from a closed Excel workbook (or group of workbooks, read this article: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee692882.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Parfait.

Actually I made new code with help of your code then worked fine.. but only problem is that It's takes 5-6 seconds to retrieve data using following code.

```
Dim db As Database
Dim rst As Recordset
Dim myPath As String, myFile As String
Dim sql As String    

    myPath = "C:\IFSC\"
    myFile = Dir(myPath & "*xls")
    Set db = CurrentDb

   ' LOOP THROUGH FOLDER
    Do While Len(myFile) > 0
        sql = "SELECT [BANK], [BRANCH],[ADDRESS],[IFSC] FROM [Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=Yes;Database=" & myPath & myFile & "].[Sheet1$];"

            Set rst = db.OpenRecordset(sql)
             Do While rst.EOF = False
                 If rst!IFSC = Me.Text1.Value Then
                     Text3 = rst!Bank
                     Text5 = rst!Branch
                     Text7 = rst!Address
                 End If
             rst.MoveNext
             Loop
             rst.Close

        myFile = Dir
    Loop
```

But problem with above code is that It finds all excel tables in Directory. If you can help then suggest me to stop loop when data matches..

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

First use MS Access, the actual database, to store all your content and not in Excel. Hence, import all 171 workbook sheets into an MS Access table. Then, you can easily query the table with form parameters.

Also, use the fact that you can directly query Excel workbooks from Access SQL without opening them, assuming sheet maintains named columns and table structure (adjacent rows/columns) of data. Adjust sheet name in query as needed.

**SQL** *(create in code or Access GUI)*

```sql
CREATE TABLE IFSC (
   ID AUTOINCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
   IFSC_Code TEXT(50),
   BankName TEXT(255)
)
```

**VBA** *(loop through all workbooks and import data)*

```
Sub ImportExcelData
   Dim myPath As String, myFile As String
   Dim sql As String

   myPath = "C:\IFSC\"
   myFile = Dir(myPath & "*xlsx")

   ' LOOP THROUGH FOLDER
   Do While Len(myFile) > 0
      sql = "INSERT INTO IFSC (IFSC_Code, BankName) " & _
             "SELECT [IFSC_Code], [BankName] " & _
             " FROM [Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=Yes;Database=" & myPath & myFile & "].[Sheet1$]"

      CurrentDb.Execute sql   ' RUN APPEND ACTION
      myFile = Dir
   Loop

End Sub
```

**SQL** *(SELECT query)*

```sql
SELECT BankName FROM IFSC WHERE [IFSC_Code] = Forms!myFormName!txtIFSC
```

**DLookup** *(assign to unbound control or as VBA variable)*

```
= DLookup("BankName", "IFSC", "[IFSC_Code] ='" &  Forms!myFormName!txtIFSC & "'"
```

Comment: I tried following but run time error "3134" syntax error in INSERT INTO Statement

Comment: There is more then 5-6 lakhs rows in total 171 excel files so database may be slow and extra data in database. So retrieve data directly from excel without importing is more beneficial. So suggest me code that way.

Comment: lakhs? Again, MS Access is an actual relational database system (RDBMS). It can absolutely hold 171 * 5 rows! In fact, well into millions unlike Excel's 1 million row limit. For the error, did you actually create the table as advised, named *IFSC*? And did you run the loop. Try running query outside with hard-coded Excel path. Be sure to change the *Sheet1* name as advised. Take an active role in this. StackOverflow is not a code-writing service.